# Fitting beta distribution over each item in a dictionary of items

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, scipy

I have a dictionary with unique ID and [sample distribution of scores] pairs, e.g.: '100': [0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.7, 0.3]. The arrays are not all the same length.

For each item/'scores' array in my dictionary, I want to fit a beta distribution like scipy.stats.beta.fit() over the distribution of scores and get the alpha/beta parameters for each sample. And then I want this in a new dictionary — so it'd be like, '101': (1.5, 1.8).

I know I could do this by iterating over my dictionary with a for-loop, but the dictionary is pretty massive/I'd like to know if there's a more computationally efficient way of doing it.

For context, the way I get this dictionary is from a pandas dataframe, where I do:

```
my_dictionary = df.groupby('unique_id')['score'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

The df looks like this:

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['100', '100', '100', '101', '101', '102'],
    'score' : [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.9]
})
```

And then the resulting dictionary looks like:

```
{'100': [0.5, 0.3, 0.2], '101': [0.2, 0.1], '102': [0.9]}
```

Is there maybe also a way of fitting the beta distribution straight from the df.groupby level/without having to convert it into a dictionary first and then looping over the dictionary with scipy? Like is there something where I could do:

```
df.groupby('unique_id')['score'].apply(stats.beta.fit()).to_dict()
```

...or something like that?

Comment: Please provide `df` data to reproduce problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think I added one! Please let me know if that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df=df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: list(beta.fit(x.score)))
dc=df.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
df
id
100    [0.2626434905176847, 0.37866242902872393, 0.18...
101    [1.253982875508286, 0.8832540117966552, -0.093...
102    [1.044551187075241, 1.0167687597781938, 0.8999...
dtype: object

dc
{'100': [0.2626434905176847, 0.37866242902872393, 0.18487097639113187, 0.3151290236088682], 
 '101': [1.253982875508286, 0.8832540117966552, -0.09383386122371801, 1.0938338612237182], 
 '102': [1.044551187075241, 1.0167687597781938, 0.8999999999999999, 1.1272504901983386e-16]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recognize You need to fit multiple beta.fit per row of dataframe `df`:

```
df['beta_fit'] = df['score'].apply( lambda x: stats.beta.fit(x))
```

Now result is stored in `df['beta_fit']`:

```
0    (0.5158954356434775, 0.4824876600627905, 0.154...
1    (0.18219650169013427, 0.18228236200252418, 0.1...
2    (2.874609362944296, 0.8497751096020354, -0.341...
3    (1.313976940871222, 0.5956397575363881, -0.093...
Name: beta_fit, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the location (`loc`) and scale (`scale`) fixed, you need to indicate this in `scipy.stats.beta.fit`. You can use `functools.partial` for this:

```
import pandas as pd
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> from functools import partial
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...         'id': ['100', '100', '100', '101', '101', '102'],
...         'score' : [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.9]
...     })
>>> beta = partial(scipy.stats.beta.fit, floc=0, fscale=1)
>>> df.groupby('id')['score'].apply(beta)
id
100      (4.82261025047374, 9.616623800842953, 0, 1)
101    (0.7079910251948778, 0.910200073771759, 0, 1)
Name: score, dtype: object
```

Note that I have adjusted your input example, since it contains an incorrect value (1.0), and too few values for the fit to succeed in some cases.